Corpse-like old man in an elevator is floating above the floor
This is a foreign language film, possibly Korean.
I can remember a couple of scenes,  hope they are from the same film and I'm not merging two different films together.
It centres around a lady who moved into an apartment block. The neighbours have recently lost their son, and I remember they have some kind of temple/memorial outside their apartment. At one point in the film this lady sees the young boy outside the family apartment, he runs off and jumps out of a window.
Another scene is set the elevator. The lady is travelling in the elevator when she becomes aware of an old man standing behind her. The camera shows that this man is actually floating, there is a shot of his feet clearly being off the floor, he looks corpse-like. He floats over towards her. I don't remember what happens next.
I probably saw this 6-10 years ago.

The film in question is  Jian Gui (The Eye)
From the Monster Mash site:

Released in 2002, Pang Brothers’ The Eye is an effectively creepy ghost story. It starts out fairly conventionally, with scene after scene of supernatural goings on: scary ghost grannies wandering poorly lit hospital halls; forlorn ghost lovers haunting their still-living flames; repentant ghost boys endlessly repeating their suicides; or (in one of the scariest moments in cinema ever) floating, concave-headed old-man ghosts in elevators who lack the concept of personal space.


